# What does Ryanair do without Sick Bags?

Tags: commercial-aviation, ryanair

Sorry for the slightly strange question, but Ryanair (Europe's Largest Low Cost Carrier) decided that seat back pockets took too much effort and got rid of them, and it appears the sick bags in the process.

[image: Ryanair Interior]
<sub>(source: [poloconghaile.com](https://poloconghaile.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Ryanair-flight-interior.jpg))</sub>

So the question comes up...

What happens **when Ryanair flights encounter turbulence**? I can hardly imagine the Flight Attendants handing out bags ad-hoc when it's sufficiently shaky to cause motion sickness among the passengers.

Comment: Well, what they save in sic sacs they'll easily spend on cabin cleaning. Next step: Hard plastic / vinyl cabins that can be hosed out after every flight? (Also, [this video is obligatory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAg0lUYHHFc))

Comment: BYOB - Bring your own bags

Comment: @flyingfisch O'Leary has been accused of hinting at a lot of things. I don't think they'll charge for a sick bag as it's more expensive to clean up the aircraft (and I don't think they can charge you for that, at least not if they didn't give you any choice). RyanAir is about cutting costs at every corner, not about screwing people over (although sometimes it does amount to that), but given two options, I'm pretty sure they'll certainly pick the cheaper one, which in this case means giving you a bag if you ask for it.

Comment: @voretaq7: they don't clean it, that saves more money. By going green and letting natural decomposition take its toll, they are helping to support many animals on Earth and improve their chances of living.

Comment: LOL @Qantas94Heavy! Very environmentally friendly of them!

Answer (score 12):

Well how many people get airsick during each flight and how many of those really vomit? And of those, how many actually use the provided sick bags? I'm not familiar with getting air sick but I'm sure there are not a lot people really using these bags. There is also no legal requirement for having sick bags. It is an item for 'additional passenger comfort'. Ryanair probably thought this way and so they saved some more money.

They also don't hand out sick bags when they are encountering chops but I'm sure they will have one for you if you ask them.

Comment: most of the time I've seen someone nearly-sick, they call the attendant proactively to get relief with water or other creature-comforts that they know can calm their symptoms.

Comment: Maybe the idea is that they expect frequent fliers to get in the habit of carrying sick sacks to hand out to the passengers seated adjacent to them, to save on dry cleaning bills etc.

Comment: @quietflyer - Damnit. Just one more thing that I have to put in my carry on. I actually used to do that in the military for new paratroopers. The alternative was enduring the mix of smells in the back of a military aircraft. Since, the alternative to my sick sack was to have the private throw up in their k-pots (which they had to wear for the jump), or inside their t-shirts.